# Convert time to easy to read strings

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

Whats the best way to get a datetime from sql server and convert it to use friendly strings like so:

if its more than 1 day > 1 Day ago.
more than 7 days > 1 weeks ago
1 year ago
3 minutes ago
56 seconds ago.

etc. Can this be done easily?

Comment: Duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/calculating-relative-time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet is to make a `DateTime` extension method:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static string ToRelative(this DateTime value)
    {        
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now; //maybe UtcNow if you're into that

        TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(now.Ticks - value.Ticks);
        double seconds = Math.Abs(ts.TotalSeconds);

        if (seconds < 60)
            return string.Format("{0} seconds ago", span.Seconds);

        if (seconds < 2700)
            return string.Format("{0} minutes ago", span.Minutes);

        if (seconds < 86400)
            return string.Format("{0} hours ago", span.Hours);

        // repeat for greater "ago" times...
    }
}
```

Then make your call on your `DateTime` value like so:

```
myDateTime.ToRelative();
```

Comment: Is it possible to bind a datagrid column in asp.net to TimeStarted.ToAgo()?

Comment: should be, though you may have to do that in an `ItemDataBound` event. Is this windows or web?

Comment: If you don't use UTC or `DateTimeOffset`, you're asking for trouble here.  Even if all values were produced in the same timezone, you'll have inaccurate answers around daylight savings time changes.  Also - by using `Math.Abs`, you are excluding future dates that you might want to say "from now" instead of "ago"

Comment: @MattJohnson, it's just an example, clearly it is incomplete. Good points, though.

Comment: @hunter agreed.  Good example, just want to make sure the OP understands context is important with dates. Thanks.